# Define variable for equation

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there I have a code that checks through a column to see for any values >0 if there is it would copy paste that column to sheet one else it would just display a pop up message.

Tried doing the code but I am unable to define `a` Hence i would need some help with that. Thanks in adv:)

This is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestPasteColumnData2()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lastrow
    a = Cells(i, "C").Value
    If a < 0 Then

     MsgBox ("No Value")
     Exit Sub

   Else

   Sheets("WF - L12 (3)").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)

   End If

   Next
  MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub

Sub TestPasteColumnData3()

Dim lastcol As Long
Dim j As Long

    With Worksheets("WF - L12 (3)")
    lastcol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       For j = 3 To lastcol
        If CBool(Application.CountIfs(.Columns(j), ">0")) Then
            .Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Value")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you even using `a` if you have `Option Explicit` in place and neglect to declare `a` ?

Comment: `a` isn't declared. With `Option Explicit` on, your code won't compile. `Dim a As Long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sup>... that checks through a column to see for any values >0 if there is it would copy paste that column to sheet one ...</sup>

```
Sub TestPasteColumnData2()

    With Worksheets("WF - L12 (3)")
        If CBool(Application.CountIfs(.Columns(3), ">0")) Then
            .Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)
        Else
            MsgBox ("No Value")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i would further want to make adjustment by looping through each column and check if there is any values>0 and paste it into another sheet accordingly.  How do i go about looping to each column? Using last column and a foreach statement? Or is there a simpler way out?:)

Comment: The code i tried is Sub TestPasteColumnData3() in the recent edit to the question above

Comment: I suppose that if you changed the **3** in `.Columns(3)` to a numerical variable and used a `For i=3 to 10` loop then you would cycle through the columns numerically. Please consider asking a new question or this might turn into a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625).

Answer (score 3):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestPasteColumnData2()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Integer ' Added Declaration        
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To lastrow
    a = Cells(i, 3).Value  ' Put column no. insted of "C"
    If a < 0 Then

     MsgBox ("No Value")
     Exit Sub

   Else

   Sheets("WF - L12 (3)").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)

   End If

   Next
  MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Please  make the 2 changes indicated above. Your program should work.

Comment: At the time of writing and posting thsese corrections I was not aware that @Jeeped  has also put right guding comment. Please give credit to him.

Comment: Thanks for the shout out. fwiw, the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) *should* be able to accept either **3** or **"C"** as the *column_num* parameter.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for correcting me regarding Range.Cells property

Comment: Hi thanks alot but i am getting a  type mismatch error for a

Comment: @Niva your code for Data3 is having destination as sheet1.Columns(3) so values are getting pasted there finally of last column. If you want column to column correspondence you will have to modify your code. Sample file [data3.xlsm][1] <https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgan2wbiy7stlwc/data3.xlsm?dl=0> has been uploaded for your perusal

Comment: thank you:) I cant access drop box here but  i will go home and check it out